# Objects on WFS-Layer don't display, ave/adv server

Tags: qgis, wfs

For some time I've been trying to add WFS-Layer to my QGIS Projects - without success.
Every time I try the regular way (add Layer->WFS-> enter settings-> choose Layer->add) I don't get any objects and in the Layer in the Layer overview shows a table icon. I still have an old version of the WFS Layer from a year ago that still works. I figured out that the difference might be the type of WFS ave (old) and adv (new) so I also tried adding the Layer using the add-on WFS 2.0 Client. This did result in a new Layer but still without any objects.

I'd like to find out why I can´t add WFS Layers the regular way and why I don't have any objects I can work with anymore.

Here a screenshot that might explain the problem
[image]

Comment: Can you load other WFS services and only the specific service you ask about does not work?

Comment: please add details of the WFS servers that you are using

Comment: Yes, I can add other WFS Layers. It seems to be a problem just with this Layer. The source is https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_aaa-modell-basiert 
I assumed it was a chance in the WFS type since it changed from ave to adv.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the new service

```
https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_aaa-modell-basiert?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities
```

is providing complex features

```
https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_aaa-modell-basiert?service=WFS&request=DescribeFeatureType&typename=adv:AX_BesondererTopographischerPunkt&version=2.0.0&
```

gives:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:adv="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" targetNamespace="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" schemaLocation="http://www.wfs.nrw.de/aaa-suite/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd"/>
<element name="AX_BesondererTopographischerPunkt" substitutionGroup="adv:AA_ZUSO" type="adv:AX_BesondererTopographischerPunktType"/>
<element abstract="true" name="AA_ZUSO" substitutionGroup="adv:AA_Objekt" type="adv:AA_ZUSOType"/>
<complexType name="AX_BesondererTopographischerPunktType">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="adv:AA_ZUSOType">
        <sequence>
            <element minOccurs="0" name="punktkennung" type="string"/>
            <element minOccurs="0" name="zustaendigeStelle" type="adv:AX_Dienststelle_SchluesselPropertyType"/>
            <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="sonstigeEigenschaft" type="string"/>
        </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
<element abstract="true" name="AA_Objekt" substitutionGroup="gml:AbstractFeature" type="adv:AA_ObjektType"/>
<complexType abstract="true" name="AA_ZUSOType">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="adv:AA_ObjektType">
        <sequence>
        <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="bestehtAus" type="gml:ReferenceType"/>
        </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

...

and standard QGIS can't handle complex feature WFS

You may find that you can use the `QGIS GML Application Schema Toolbox` plugin to access the service